# 403 Forbidden when calling get products or get customers

Tags: shopify

I am working on a private app for Shopify, and I can successfully download a list of orders in XML format using GET /admin/orders.xml. However, when I try to get a list of customers or products, I get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Could you make this a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your App has permissions to READ Customer or Product resources.

Comment: How do I do that? Your documentation seems to refer to public apps, not private ones.